# Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in order clause is ambiguous

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

```
$banks_transactions = DB::table('finance_banking_transactions')
        ->join('finance_banks', 'finance_banking_transactions.bank_id', "=", 'finance_banks.id')
        ->latest()->paginate(20);
```

How do i solve the error `` SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in order clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `finance_banking_transactions` inner join `finance_banks` on `finance_banking_transactions`.`bank_id` = `finance_banks`.`id` order by `created_at` desc limit 20 offset 0)" `` and I have the column

Comment: Remove `->get()`

Comment: Why not check what each intermediate function call returns?

Comment: ```SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in order clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `finance_banking_transactions` inner join `finance_banks` on `finance_banking_transactions`.`bank_id` = `finance_banks`.`id` order by `created_at` desc limit 20 offset 0)"``` @apokryfos i get this

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If there was any such error message, why not fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Because you use join, you need to specify latest().

for example, `latest('finance_banking_transactions.created_at')`, or instead using `latest()`, you can use `orderBy('finance_banking_transactions.created_at')`